# Updating a column from 1 Dataframe where other Dataframe has same keys

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like this,

```
Key Group RS
42 23 100
42 41 21
46 23 89
67 10 65
```

Other dataframe is like this,

```
Key Group RS
42 41 11
67 10 23
```

There is hierarchy: Key -> Group(unique within key) -> RS.

I wanted to replace the RS value in first dataframe if the Key and Group are same with second dataframe.
So result should be like,

```
Key Group RS
42 23 100
42 41 11 // updated
46 23 89
67 10 23 // updated
```

I wanted to use the pandas `.update` function but it won't work with non-unique indexes, which is the case for Key as it repeats in multiple rows. I am confused on what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pd.concat` +`drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],0).drop_duplicates(['Key','Group'],keep='last')
Out[1107]: 
   Key  Group   RS
0   42     23  100
2   46     23   89
0   42     41   11
1   67     10   23
```

Comment: Whoa this is very unique, simple, and it is running faster than earlier ones! :P need to change the verified answer

Comment: Although I had to stack a `.sort_values(by="Key")` at end to make the keys be together. Even with that extra step of sorting it was faster.

Comment: @Trion glad it help

Comment: I associate you with `drop_duplicates` (-:

Answer (score 4):

Set indices and use `loc` to assign updated values.  Then reset the index.
Note that this approach preserves the `dtype` of the `'RS'` column.

```
d1 = df1.set_index(cols).RS
d2 = df2.set_index(cols).RS
d1.loc[d2.index] = d2
d1.reset_index()

   Key  Group   RS
0   42     23  100
1   42     41   11
2   46     23   89
3   67     10   23
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way

```
In [718]: cols = ['Key', 'Group']

In [719]: df2.set_index(cols).combine_first(df1.set_index(cols)).reset_index()
Out[719]:
   Key  Group     RS
0   42     23  100.0
1   42     41   11.0
2   46     23   89.0
3   67     10   23.0
```

---

Details

```
In [720]: df1
Out[720]:
   Key  Group   RS
0   42     23  100
1   42     41   21
2   46     23   89
3   67     10   65

In [721]: df2
Out[721]:
   Key  Group  RS
0   42     41  11
1   67     10  23
```

Comment: sorry, had to switch the accepted answer to other one as it was more fast.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can consider is updating your index (`key`) to be unique, then using the update method you mentioned. Another way might be to iterate through both arrays, updating as you go, but that's not as elegant.

Another thing you could try is using multi-index to recover uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't possible to change the uniqueness, thanks for giving an answer though

Comment: Well suppose you make a new column, equal to say `10 * key  + i` where you use `i` to differentiate the unique occurrences.